# Angular pass parameters and receive json

Tags: angularjs, json

I am using this service to get json data. How can I pass two parameters as well. With the json I need to populate a drop down.

```
     myApp.service('allCurrentSettingsService', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
        var allSettings = null;
        this.getList = function () {
            var def = $q.defer()
            if (allSettings) {
                def.resolve(allSettings);
            } else {
                $http.post('GetAllCurrentSettings', { companyName: compName, customerName: custName })
                  .then(function (response) {
                      var response = $.parseJSON(response.data)
                      allSettings = response;
                      def.resolve(allSettings);
                  });
            }
            return def.promise;
        }
    }]);
```

And here I am calling the service:

```
    myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'getDocTypesService',
    function ($scope, getDocTypesService) {
    $scope.getDocTypes = '';
    getDocTypesService.getList(compName, custName).then(function (value ) {
    $scope.getDocTypes = value
    });
}
```

]);

Comment: Where would you like to add parameters ? Query ? Url params ? body ?

Comment: are the two parameters going from angular to your service, or from your service to angular?

Comment: Thank you. The parameters are going from angular service to my mvc controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the function parameters. Please add the same in function definition.

```js
this.getList = function (compName, custName) {
            var def = $q.defer()
            if (allSettings) {
                def.resolve(allSettings);
            } else {
                $http.post('GetAllCurrentSettings', { companyName: compName, customerName: custName })
                  .then(function (response) {
                      var response = $.parseJSON(response.data)
                      allSettings = response;
                      def.resolve(allSettings);
                  });
            }
            return def.promise;
        }
```

You can call the $http.post() in other ways also:

```js
 var data = {param:'val1',.....}
    $http({
    url: "time.php",
    method: "POST",
    params: data
    })
```

Comment: Thank you . Could you show me how to add these parameters when I am calling the service, I added the code.

Comment: In your service , you missed to accept the parameters sending from controller. It should be like  this : this.getList = function (compName, custName) . And these parameters only you are sending with http call .